# Call a perl routine with parameters

Tags: c, perl, xs

I need to call a perl routine in my C program. The perl routine takes the following arguments: `$a, $b, $c`,  where `$a` and `$b` are integers, `$c` is a string (may contain binary characters). According to [perlcall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html), here are the means of making the call.

```
I32 call_sv(SV* sv, I32 flags);
I32 call_pv(char *subname, I32 flags);
I32 call_method(char *methname, I32 flags);
I32 call_argv(char *subname, I32 flags, char **argv);
```

Seems that I can only use call_argv(...), but there are two questions

- how do I pass an integer to the perl routine
- how do I pass a (binary) string to perl?

Wish there is a function like

```
I32 call_argv(char *subname, I32 flags, int numOfArgs, SV* a, SV* b, SV *c ...);
```

Comment: perlcall has a section labeled "Passing Parameters" for a reason. You do it by putting items onto the Perl stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [Passing Parameters section of perlcall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html#Passing-Parameters).  Arguments are pushed on the Perl stack. `call_argv` isn't useful for passing anything other than strings. The calling convention would look something like

```
PUSHMARK(SP);
mPUSHi(some_integer);
mPUSHp(binary_data, len);
XPUSHs(some_SV_I_had_laying_around);
PUTBACK;
call_pv("sub_name", G_DISCARD);
```

or you can use `call_sv` if you have the subname in an `SV*`, or `call_method` to call a method by name on some object.

If the sub returns a value or values then you can call it with `G_SCALAR` or `G_ARRAY` and use the `POP` macros to access the return values; this is detailed in the following two sections. Don't forget to `SPAGAIN`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! The example in the "Passing Parameters" section is exactly what I was looking for.  Should have read the whole manual before asking :-(

Comment: A slight neatening of that code is to use the `mPUSH*` family instead, as they mortalise the SV they push. Also there's a few specific ones; like `mPUSHi` for IVs and `mPUSHp` for PVs.